# Where to learn ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I've been learning ActionScript 2.0 at school, so that's the only thing I know, but I want to go over to ActionScript 3.0.

I've searched up some places to learn it, but many of the tutorials, lessons and books are for years back, so I will get errors etc, because the code either doesn't exist any longer etc.

So my question is, where should I start learning?

IF possible, I would love to have "tasks" to do, because I love having fun while learning, but of course, if it's the only opinion, then I'll learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break your learning down into these topics, in order of priority. A Google search or look through the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) will explain each in adequate detail.

1. Language basics

   - [Operators](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html).
   - [Statements, Keywords & Directives](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html).
   - [Top level functions and classes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html).
   - Storing data in Objects, Arrays & Vectors.
   - Garbage collection.
2. The [display architecture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e58.html).

   - The document root.
   - The Stage.
   - DisplayObjects and DisplayObjectContainers.
   - Creating library symbols and exporting them for ActionScript.
3. The Event model.

   - Listening for and reacting to events.
   - Dispatching events.
4. Object Oriented Programming.

   - Creating a document class.
   - Defining classes.
   - Creating instances of classes.
   - Building relationships between class instances.